# implicit wait is not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to wait on an element to be visible so i have set a implicit wait in the method bellow:

```
    public boolean isDisplayed(String xpathElement,int timeOut ) {
    boolean found = true;

    try {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( timeOut , TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        driver.findElement( By.xpath( xpathElement ) ).isDisplayed();

    } catch( NoSuchElementException e ) {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
        found = false;
    }
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait( 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
    return found;
}
```

I nullify the implicit wait because i use the `webDriverWait` and i don't want to have issues, but the `isDisplayed()` shows that the element is still not visible and it show that the time out is 0 seconds and not the timeout that was passed in the method.

Comment: Is there any reason why you've chosen to not use the 'explicit wait' functionality which might suit your purpose?

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your comment the thing is that i Want to have this method available thru all of my project and not depend on a specific test case, but you right i can actually use explicit wait "elemenetToBeClicable" and it would've solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem actually was related to the visibility of the element the element wasn't visible for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are doing a mistake while using `.isDisplayed()`. You must have used selenium webdriver's `isDisplayed()` and your code shows that you are very intended to use 0 sec timeout. So it could be a reason you see 0 secs in execution log.

Suggestion: Change your method name and use it again.

Comment: Hi P, thank you for your comment, i am actually using the customed isDisplay() method and the implicit wait is set to 0 after the element is is failed to be displayed and after the element is visible, so it shouldn't be the problem.